# SWI-Prolog: Check element membership in multiple lists

Tags: list, prolog

So I have a membership function, which tells me when `X` is not in `L`:

```
not_in(X, L) :- not(member(X,L)).
```

Which works as desired:

```
83 ?- not_in(5,[3,4]).
true.
```

However, I also have a function that produces many lists:

```
84 ?- manyLists(_,L).
L = [5, 11] ;
L = [3, 4] ;
L = [16, 22] ;
false.
```

What I want to do is check that `X` is not in any of the lists:

```
manyLists(_,L), not_in(X,L).
```

However, this returns:

```
85 ?- manyLists(_,L), not_in(32,L).
L = [5, 11] ;
L = [3, 4] ;
L = [16, 22] ;
false.
```

I.e. it should return true, because 32 is not in any of those lists.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, but you are maybe not *interpreting* correctly the solutions you get.

First, when you have a predicate that succeeds more than once, this is called (somewhat misleadingly) a **non-deterministic** behaviour: one *query* returns multiple *solutions*.

Say you ask, "which number is between 1 and 3?":

```
?- between(1, 3, X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

You get three solutions. Each has one *variable binding* in it: `X = 1`, `X = 2`, and `X = 3`.

```
?- between(1, 3, X), succ(X, Y).
X = 1, Y = 2 ;
X = 2, Y = 3 ;
X = 3, Y = 4.
```

Now each solutions has two variable bindings.

```
?- between(1, 3, X), X rem 2 =:= 0.
X = 2 ;
false.
```

If you have trouble seeing how Prolog goes about trying to find a proof for the last query, you could even look at the actual proof tree:

```
?- trace(between/3), trace('=:='/2).
%         between/3: [call,redo,exit,fail]
%         (=:=)/2: [call,redo,exit,fail]
true.

[debug]  ?- between(1, 3, X), X rem 2 =:= 0.
 T Call: (8) between(1, 3, _G1248)
 T Exit: (8) between(1, 3, 1)
 T Call: (8) 1 rem 2=:=0
 T Fail: (8) 1 rem 2=:=0
 T Redo: (8) between(1, 3, _G1248)
 T Exit: (8) between(1, 3, 2)
 T Call: (8) 2 rem 2=:=0
 T Exit: (8) 2 rem 2=:=0
X = 2 ;
 T Redo: (8) between(1, 3, _G1248)
 T Exit: (8) between(1, 3, 3)
 T Call: (8) 3 rem 2=:=0
 T Fail: (8) 3 rem 2=:=0
false.
```

To your question: you want to show that **for all** possible bindings of your list, a number is not in that list.

Your original query, simplified:

```
?- ( L = [5,11] ; L = [3,4] ; L = [16,22] ), \+ member(32, L).
L = [5, 11] ;
L = [3, 4] ;
L = [16, 22].
```

Wrapping it in the SWI-Prolog predicate [`forall/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2):

```
?- forall( ( L = [5,11] ; L = [3,4] ; L = [16,22] ), \+ member(32, L) ).
true.

?- forall( ( L = [5,11] ; L = [3,4] ; L = [16,22] ), \+ member(3, L) ).
false.
```

If you look at the help of `forall/2`, you will see that `forall(Cond, Action)` has the semantics `\+ ( Cond, \+ Action )`, which is: "There is no condition for which action cannot be proved."

```
?- \+ ( ( L = [5,11] ; L = [3,4] ; L = [16,22] ), \+ \+ member(32, L) ).
true.
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you very much for the explanation!